# How to change images sequence dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-reel

I would like to change the images sequence dynamically.

For example, in the below link, currently there is a car image.

http://test.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel/example/object-movie-multi-row-sequence/

On some action, I would like to switch to another car image.
Currently, I tried doing the following.

```
$('#image').reel({images: 'images/abc_##.jpg'});
```

The above code is working fine, except that there was some flickering effect for a second on switching to other image. Is there a way to change image without that flickering effect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Every time we changed the image sequence, it flickered to the original img-src image defined in the html. But

```
$('#image').reel({images: 'images/abc_##.jpg'});
$('#image').attr("src", 'images/abc_01.jpg');
```

removed the flicker, where `images/abc_01.jpg` is the first image in the reel sequence. Curiously, having the `attr()` call before the `reel()` call didn't work. Also make sure you redefine all the `reel()` options, they get dumped when you recreate the reel.

Comment: I found this did not fully work for me.  It depends on what point in the interval it was at.  So occasionally it flickered.  The fix was to set the attribute at time of reel change and afterwards.  So to modify your code: $('#image').reel({images: 'images/abc_##.jpg', attr: {img: 'images/abc_01.jpg'}}); $('#image').attr("src", 'images/abc_01.jpg');